# Is it possible for a person to eat so many carrots that one turns orange?

Tags: human-biology, medicine, skin, diet

I once read that Jerry Rubin (a famous 1960s activist) ate so many carrots that he turned orange. (This was in the *East Bay Express,* around twenty years ago.) I assumed it could be true, though he would have to eat hundreds or thousands of carrots; while a close family member thinks it's ridiculous. Is it medically/biologically plausible?

(I hope this question is appropriate to ask here--I'm new to this forum.)

Comment: @TanMath: As I said, this claim was from an article in the _East Bay Express,_ around 20 years ago. The article was about history/politics/ "where are they now" about Jerry Rubin, or the Yippies (a hippie group that included Rubin and the more famous Abbie Hoffman).

Answer (score 3):

Beta-carotene, the pigment that gives carrots their orange colour, can accumulate in the skin if taken in excess amounts. This condition is called carotenosis. Since beta-carotene is a lipohilic (fat loving: dissolves in lipids), its absorption is facilitated by dietary fats [<sup>[1]</sup>](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8424385).

There is one report that says that excessive consumption of beta-carotene containing fruits and vegetables can lead to carotenosis [<sup>[2]</sup>](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20868341).

Also have a look at [this Scientific American blog](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/scicurious-brain/friday-weird-science-too-many-carrots-and-why-you-should-believe-your-dad/).

---

1. Prince, Martin R., and Joan K. Frisoli. "[**Beta-carotene accumulation in serum and skin.**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8424385)" *The American journal of clinical nutrition* 57.2 (1993): 175-181.
2. Wageesha, Nekadage Don Amal, et al. "[**Studies on hypercarotenemia due to excessive ingestion of carrot, pumpkin and papaw.**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20868341)" *International journal of food sciences and nutrition* 62.1 (2011): 20-25.

Comment: Thanks. But how many carrots would an adult need to eat?

Comment: @user24353 That I am not sure of. It may vary between person to person and would also depend on the kind of diet one is having.